# Dompdf stream to screen

Tags: php

I have got a new challenge, to save the html invoice into pdf which I have done but also want to stream it on screen once its saved. The code i have used to convert is

```
$cur_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($cur_dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

class pdfCreator {
    private $curDir;{

    public function __construct() {
        global $cur_dir;
        $this->curDir = $cur_dir;
    }

    private function getHtml() {
        ob_start();
        include($this->curDir . '/template.php');
        $retStr = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $retStr;
    }

    public function getPdf() {      
        $html = $this->getHtml();
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $output = $dompdf->output();

        $pdfFileName = $this->curDir.'/invoice.pdf';
        file_put_contents($pdfFileName, $output);
    }
}


$pdfCreator = new pdfCreator();
$pdfCreator->getPdf();

}
```

If any one can help me to tell how to stream it on screen would be a great help.

Thank You

Comment: found he answer $dompdf->stream("invoice.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));

Answer (score 0):

something like so:

```
            $size = filesize($pdfFileName);
            header("Content-length: $size");
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");
            header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$pdfFileName");
            readfile($pdfFileName);
            exit();
```